# Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 (help please)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I use this statements to do add a constraint or to add a foreign key.

```
USE Kudler1_FF
ALTER TABLE Employee_Tbl
ADD FOREIGN KEY (JobTitle)
REFERENCE Job_Tbl (JobTitle)
```

and this one:

```
Alter TABLE Employee_Tbl
ADD Constraint FK_JobTitle
FOREIGN KEY (JobTitle) 
REFERENCES Job_Tbl(JobTitle)
```

but now I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_JobTitle". The conflict occurred in database "Kudler1_FF", table
>   "dbo.Job_Tbl", column 'JobTitle'.

Comment: Check of your tables already have the Foreign keys for `JobTitle`.

Comment: Did you run them both? they do the same thing, the first just gives the constraint a default guid-type name.  Use SSMS UI to expand your table in Object Explorer, then look under 'keys' to find the one with the guid-type name.  alter your table and drop that key, then run your second statement that names the foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

The table Employee_Tbl must be empty before you create the constraint or the foreign key because the database engine will validate the data present on this table. If the table already have some data that does not match with Job_Tbl, you will get the error message. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error while adding a record to a child table where that record is not present in the parent table. This happens while inserting the records.

Your problem is the same, you have already some records in the child table `Employee` that are not present in the parent table `Job_Tbl`